# Creating a Discord-Style Mouse Parallax Effect in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, parallax

I am trying to achieve a mouse parallax effect similar to what can be seen on the Discord login page (for reference: [Discord Login Page](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorized)). I have created a particle animation in my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code, but I am having difficulty implementing the desired mouse parallax effect.

```js
const particlesContainer = document.getElementById('particles-container');
let particleCount = 300; // Adjust the initial particle count
const particles = [];

// Create particles
for (let i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
  createParticle();
}

function createParticle() {
  const particle = document.createElement('div');
  particle.className = 'particle';

  const size = Math.random() * 2 + 2; // Random size between 2px and 4px
  const x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
  const y = Math.random() * window.innerHeight;
  const color = getRandomColor();

  particle.style.width = `${size}px`;
  particle.style.height = `${size}px`;
  particle.style.left = `${x}px`;
  particle.style.top = `${y}px`;
  particle.style.background = color;

  particlesContainer.appendChild(particle);

  // Store particles in the array
  particles.push({
    element: particle,
    x,
    y,
    speedY: Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.1, // Slower vertical speed
    speedX: Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.1, // Slower horizontal speed
  });
}

// Animation loop
function animateParticles() {
  for (const particle of particles) {
    // Update particle positions for a parallax effect
    particle.x -= particle.speedX; // Added horizontal motion
    particle.y -= particle.speedY; // Added vertical motion

    // Reset particle position if it goes above the viewport
    if (particle.y < 0) {
      particle.y = window.innerHeight + Math.random() * 100;
      particle.x = Math.random() * window.innerWidth;
    }

    // Apply the new position
    particle.element.style.transform = `translate(${particle.x}px, ${particle.y}px)`;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animateParticles);
}

// Helper function to generate random colors
function getRandomColor() {
  const colors = ['#ffffff', '#dddddd', '#666666']; // White, light gray, and dark gray
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

// Start the animation loop
animateParticles();
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.particles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Style the particles */

.particle {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Color of particles */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* Make them circular */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* Prevent particles from blocking mouse events */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Center particles on their positions */
}


/* Add z-index for particles */

.particle {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="particles" id="particles-container"></div>
</div>
```

In my current code, I have a particle animation that moves particles independently within the viewport. However, I want to add a mouse parallax effect similar to the one on the Discord login page, where particles move in response to the mouse cursor's movement but do not follow the cursor directly.

I am looking for guidance on how to modify my existing code to achieve this effect. Specifically, I want to know how to update the particle positions based on the mouse movement while maintaining the particles' independent animations.

Any help or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

"I have already attempted to create a particle animation in my HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code. I followed a tutorial and successfully generated a particle animation that moves independently within the viewport. However, my goal is to add a mouse parallax effect similar to the one seen on the Discord login page.

What I tried:

Created a particle animation with random movement.
Added event listeners to detect mouse movement.
Experimented with adjusting particle positions based on mouse coordinates.
What I expected:
I expected the particles to respond to the mouse cursor's movement in a parallax-like fashion, similar to the Discord login page.

What actually resulted:
The particles in my animation either followed the cursor too closely or did not respond to the mouse movement as desired. My current code does not achieve the desired mouse parallax effect."